# Trying to understand the proof of the main theorem in Tannakian categories

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory

I am trying to understand Lemma 2.13 in [Deligne and Milne's Tannakian Categories](https://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/tc.pdf)

Lemma: Let $C$ be a $k-$linear abelian category and let $\omega:C\to\text{Vec}_k$ be a $k-$linear exact faithful functor. Then, there is a natural action of $A_X$ on $\omega(Y)$, $Y\in\left \langle X\right \rangle$, and $\omega$ defines an equivalence of categories $\left \langle X\right \rangle\to\text{Mod}_{A_X}$ carying $\omega|\left \langle X \right \rangle$ to the forgetful functor and $A_X=\text{End}(\omega|\left \langle X \right \rangle)$.

Here, $X\in\text{ob}(C)$, $A_X$ is the largest $k-$subalgebra of $\text{End}(\omega(X))$ stabilizing $\omega(Y)$ for all $Y\subset X^n$ and $\left \langle X \right \rangle$ is the full subcategory of $C$ whose objects are those isomorphic to a subquotient of $X^n$ for some $n$.

My question is: **How does an arbitrary element $a\in A_X$ define an endomorphism of $\omega|\left \langle X \right \rangle$?** In other words, we need to show the following diagram is commutative for every $f\in\text{Hom}(X,X)$:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\omega X @>{a}>> \omega X\\
@V\omega fVV @VV\omega fV\\
\omega X @>{a}>> \omega X
\end{CD}
because these commutative diagrams induce all the other commutative diagrams.

Equivalently, we need to show that $\omega(\text{Hom}(X,X))\subset \text{Hom}_{A_X}(\omega X,\omega X)$, and it means that $\omega|\left \langle X \right \rangle$ factors through $\text{Mod}_{A_X}$. In the note, Deligne and Milne don't explain these things, or am I missing something?